# Please help me with this HTML table

Tags: html, html-table

I need as fast as possible a table in HTML like this:

[image: http://imgur.com/qwXRthd]

Comment: You should never use expressions like "I need [this] as fast as possible" on Stack Overflow. Be aware that people here spend their free time answering questions. They do not earn money for that, so they do not need extra pressure. Moreover, SO is not a free code-writing service. You are supposed to share your code and ask for help only when you are stuck somewhere in your experimentations. With that said, happy coding! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following html should be ok:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th colspan="2"></th>
    <th rowspan="2"></th>
    <th rowspan="2"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="5"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/gc6HryToTGrs6hhymWhJ)

In case you need to change it or make an other you can use this tool: http://www.tablesgenerator.com/html_tables#

Comment: Love you man! :D

Comment: @alexfc23 Validate the answer if it's ok for you :)

Answer (score 0):

here it is..

```html
<table border="1" style="width: 464px; height: 122px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="background-color: #00ff00;">Jon</td>
<td colspan="2" style="background-color: #00ff00;">Nume part</td>
<td rowspan="2" style="background-color: #00ff00;">CLASS</td>
<td rowspan="2" style="background-color: #00ff00;">TOTAL<br />PART</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan="5">ALBA</td>
<td style="background-color: #00ff00;">senti</td>
<td style="background-color: #00ff00;">Penti C#</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td rowspan="4"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```